# Update one column from substring of another column

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have an existing column that I would like to take a subset of and insert into a second (new) column in the same table.

e.g. MyTable.[FullName] (existing column) contains a string like "P-13-146 PS - Goodyear - Tire repair"

I created a new column, MyTable.[ShortName] that I want to insert a substring of the value from the first column into ("P-13-146 PS"). The problem is that the length of the substring is different for each full name. The only real consistency is that I want up to the second whitespace character.

I am trying to resolve the following:

UPDATE [MyTable] SET [ShortName] = ???

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try  this:

```
declare @exp varchar(200)
set @exp='P-13-146 PS - Goodyear - Tire repair'

select RTRIM(SUBSTRING(@exp,1,CHARINDEX(' ',@exp,charindex(' ',@exp)+1)))
```

Comment: Minor edit to your code and it worked perfectly! Thanks! Just waiting for the timer to elapse so I can set your response as the answer
UPDATE [MyTable] SET [ShortName] = RTRIM(SUBSTRING([Name],1,CHARINDEX(' ',[Name],charindex(' ',[Name])+1)))

Comment: Returns an empty string if FullName has fewer than two spaces.

Answer (score 0):

Just combine the string manipulation functions until you get what you want:

```
SELECT 
CASE WHEN CHARINDEX(' ',FullName, CHARINDEX(' ', FullName)+1) = 0 THEN FullName
ELSE SUBSTRING(FullName, 1, CHARINDEX(' ',FullName, CHARINDEX(' ', FullName)+1)-1)
END ShortName
FROM MyTable
```

The first part of the CASE statement is for names that have fewer than two spaces.